# How do I allow use of both of these fields in an if statement?

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($_POST['prefix']($_POST['code'])))
    $COURSEE=mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['prefix']($_POST['code'])));
```

This gives this error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: Is that PHP? This tutorial might help you understand the form basics: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Have to agree with @Richard - a good read of the [tutorials](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) will be a lot faster than asking lots of basic questions. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're attempting to implicitly concatenate the two $_POST variables, in which case a much more legible form would be:

```
if(!empty($_POST['prefix'] . $_POST['code'])) {
    $COURSEE = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix'] . $_POST['code']);
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want to concateate if **one** of the $_POST variables was present:

```
if(!empty($_POST['prefix']) || !empty($_POST['code'])) {
    ...
```

Or if **both** of the $_POST variables are present:

```
if(!empty($_POST['prefix']) && !empty($_POST['code'])) {
    ...
```

That said, in all of the above instances, using [isset](http://www.php.net/isset) instead of `!empty` would seem somewhat more logical.

**UPDATE**

To add a space between the two $_POST variables, simply use:

```
$COURSEE = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix'] . ' ' . $_POST['code']);
```

Comment: Im trying to post these two $_POST'd values into one field

Comment: @user700070 By merging them into a single field with no separator? (If so, the above is fine.)

Comment: The only thing seperating them would be a space, so like e.g. INFO 150 would be an example of what is stored in one column in a db table

Comment: @user700070 I've updated my answer to show you how to add a space between the two variables.

Comment: This still gives the error after using if(!empty($_POST['prefix'] . $_POST['code'])) {
    $COURSEE = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix'] . ' ' . $_POST['code']);

Comment: @user700070 You're missing the closing `}`.

Comment: Middparka, this gives the error using this code if(isset($_POST['prefix'] . $_POST['code'])) {
    $COURSEE = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prefix'] . ' ' . $_POST['code']);
}

Comment: @user700070 You can't use isset like that - you'd need to use `if(isset($_POST['prefix'], $_POST['code']))`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use AND operator?

```
if(!empty(...) && !empty(...)){
   //doStuff
}
```